# Unsubscribe from channel via REST API in Parse

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

Does anyone know how to unsubscribe from a channel or all channels in parse via REST API? The documentation say you have to update the channels array, but is not working for me or i'm doing something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a section of the documentation that shows adding a channel:

https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations-updating

You would need to put the whole contents of the Installation including existing channels, plus the new one.

Alternatively you can make atomic changes to just the `channels` array as described in this section of the docs under the "Arrays" heading:

https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-updating

As shown there you can use `Add`, `AddUnique` and `Remove`. To add a single channel you're best using `AddUnique`.

So, to answer your question, you can use the `Remove` for a single channel or a couple of channels using the following parameters:

```
{"channels":{"__op":"Remove","objects":["channel 1","channel 2"]}}
```

To remove all channels you would perform an update with `channels` set to the default, e.g:

```
{
    "deviceType": "ios",
    "deviceToken": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
    "channels": [
        ""
    ]
}
```